# Elastic search installation: Running as service giving error system cannot find file specified

Tags: elasticsearch

I am installing elastic search on windows machine. I have downloaded and installed elasticsearch-1.3.0-setup-32-bit exe and jre-7u55-windows-i586 exe. I have also added JRE to my JAVA_HOME environment variable.

When i try to start elastic search as a service on my windows maching, i am getting following error:
[image]

Comment: Try checking the permissions of the file or folder for your elasticsearch user.

Comment: where exactly? everyone has full control over my elastic search installation folder

Comment: elasticsearch service should have read & write permission in the path where it is installed.

If problem remains same, try to reinstall service after restarting the machine